# Cause arrow to fade out when scrolling down within div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to cause a chevron to fade out when I scroll down. I can get it to work with the following code when I scroll down the body element:

```
<script>    
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".arrow").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
      });
</script>
```

However, the chevron is placed inside of a long div element (`id="scrollsnap-container" class="scrollsnap-container`) and I want it to fade out when I scroll down within the div (as opposed to the body itself).

I have attempted

```
$(document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container').scroll(function(){
        $(".arrow").css("opacity", 1 - $(document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container')).scrollTop() / 250);
      });
```

but am yet to have luck with that.

Comment: can you please show us some HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was loading jquery in the wrong spot (it was after this code rather than before). The code I was using worked:

```
$(document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container').scroll(function(){
        $(".arrow").css("opacity", 1 - $(document.getElementById('scrollsnap-container')).scrollTop() / 250);
      });
```

Importing jquery at the correct point resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve result with js also

```
const element=document.querySelector('ELEMENT');

window.onscroll=function(){checking()}; 

function checking(){
element.style.opacity=Math.max(0,1-(window.scrollY/250))
}
```